# How to create an array according to row and column names using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

for example i have a data like csv file:

```
 x(col)        y(row)         Value
    0               0            5
    3               1           10
    2               2            2
    1               3            6
```

output:

```
    [[5,0,0,0],
    [0,10,0,0],
    [0, 0,2,0],
    [0, 0,0,6]]
```

Comment: I think your row/col are swapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
a = (df
   .pivot_table(index='y(row)', columns='x(col)',
                values='Value', fill_value=0)
   .reindex(index=range(df['y(row)'].max()+1),
            columns=range(df['x(col)'].max()+1))
   .to_numpy()
)
```

Or numpy indexing:

```
a = np.zeros((df['y(row)'].max()+1, df['y(row)'].max()+1), dtype=df['Value'].dtype)

a[df['y(row)'], df['x(col)']] = df['Value']

print(a)
```

output:

```
array([[ 5,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the numpy function diag you can create a diagonal matrix (list of lists) from a pandas dataframe column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')  
np.diag(df.Value)
```